# how to set defaultDllDirectries to be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dl

Tags: node.js, database, api, postman

i want install postman on my  windows seven laptop, and i keep getting the pop up of "The procedure entry point SetDefaultsDiiDIrectories could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dii" what are the solutions to this